# Выполнение функции по названию JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте уважаемые пользователи проекта hashcode!
При создании для своего сайта всплывающего окна на jQuery столкнулся с проблемой - по закрытию окна требуется выполнить определённую функцию.

В идеале хотелось бы сделать так:

```
<span class="close" onclick="close()" callback="funcname">Закрыть</span>
function close() {
//....
if ($(this).attr('callback')!="") {
// Некий код который выполнит функцию funcname
}
}
```

Уже пробывал $(this).attr('callback')();, но для его работы требуется чтобы было не название функции, а callback="function(){}".
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать, мне кажется в JS есть функция вроде как: vipolnit('funcname'); но я никак не могу её найти.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/359910/1299307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать `eval`

Вот рабочий пример: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cw4Mb/1/)

HTML

```
<span class="close" data-callback="custom()">Click me!</span>
```

JS

```
function custom() {
    alert('Callback works!')
}

$('.close').click( function(){
    var callback = $(this).attr('data-callback')

    if (callback.length > 0) eval(callback)
})
```

Comment: человеку, задающему такие вопросы не стоит показывать примеры с использованием `eval`, это мощный инструмент, но пользоваться им нужно очень аккуратно, точно зная, когда и почему он лучше других средств

Comment: Благодарю.
Всё получилось! Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: В jquery правельно бы использовать var callback = $(this).data('callback')

Answer (score 1):

```
var callbackHash = {
    'funcname': function(){...} // целевая функция, которую необходимо выполнить
                                // если их несколько - дописать в хэш
};
function close() {
    //....
    var funcName = $(this).attr('callback');
    if (callbackHash[funcName]) {
        // Некий код который выполнит функцию funcname
        callbackHash[funcName]();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

извините, может я что-то не понял, но что вам мешает сделать вот так:

```
$("#Идентификатор_кнопки_закрытия").live("click", callback);

....

function callback()
{
 // что-то там
}
```

Comment: Попробую объяснить на реально-выдуманной ситуации (если я правильно понял автора). Допустим у вас есть всплывающее окно. При клике на close оно закрывается. И всё хорошо.. до тех пор пока не врывается босс и говорит, что у него гениальная идея: чтобы при закрытии **только** окна регистрации выскакивал попугай! Поэтому у автора и стоит задача расширения функционала для особенных случаев